# How to overwrite/extend existing spree classes in app/models?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, spree

I want to extend Class Role such that I can add more roles to the
roles table in Spree. My application would have different prices based
on roles.

By default roles have: ("admin" and "user") in it. I want to add more
types to the table.

Q1: Can I just extend the Role class in one of my extensions?
Q2: How can I implement (actually extend on app/models/Variant.rb) the
prices based on different roles such that it just grabs price from one
place? So that I dont have to change code in *_html.erb files where
its using price.

If I can get this to work this would be a cool extension to have on
github.

Thanks

Answer (score 5):

To extend classes in Spree, you can use Modules or `class_eval`.  Spree extensions tend to use `class_eval`.  Here's an example for extending `User` and `Variant` in a custom extension.

```
class CustomRoleExtension < Spree::Extension

  # main extension method
  def activate

    # extend User
    User.class_eval do
      def business?
        self.roles.include?("business")
      end

      def sponsor?
        self.roles.include?("sponsor")
      end

      def developer?
        self.roles.include?("developer")
      end
    end

    # extend Variant
    Variant.class_eval do
      def price_for(role)
        # ...
      end
    end
  end

end
```

To add more roles, I just added a `defaults/roles.yml` to my extension, with custom yaml blocks:

```
coach_role:
  id: 3
  name: coach

trainer_role:
  id: 4
  name: trainer

graduate_role:
  id: 5
  name: graduate
```

Then when you run `rake db:bootstrap`, it will add all those roles to the database.

Let me know if that works.

Comment: Can you give full paths (in relation to webroot)?  I'm still working out where to put what.

Comment: Oh and can't you extend the model in the your_extension/app/models/user.rb file?

Comment: viatropos, sorry for the crazy late reply but, yes, it worked. Thanks.